# Limit of function, when $x$ approaches $a$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions

So w have to estimate limit of function when the x approaches a. Function is given on real numbers by following term

$f(x)= \dfrac{\ln\frac{x}{a}}{x-a}$

Without L'Hôpital's rule.

So i go with

$\lim \limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{\ln\frac{x}{a}}{x-a}=\lim \limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{\ln(x)-ln(a)}{x-a}$

I know that this limit would be just a derivative of ln(x) at point "a", but this leaves me with nothing. So now is my question... I need any clue, how to deal with this limit. I would greatly appriciate any hint.

PS. As $\ln(x)$ I understand $\log_e(x)$. Also $ln(x)$ is for me inverse function to $e^x$

Comment: Well as you already said, the limit is equal to the derivate of $\ln(x)$ at the point $a$. You know that the derivate is  $\frac 1 x$, so the limit is equal to $\frac 1 a$.

Comment: I know that, but already on studies we haven't been given this information yet. So yes, I can say that, because I know that it is, but I can't use it, and estimate like that. I need some kind of other solution.

Comment: $\lim \limits_{x \to a}\frac{\ln(x)-ln(a)}{x-a}=\lim \limits_{x \to a}\frac{\ln(x)}{x-a}-\lim \limits_{x \to a}\frac{\ln(a)}{x-a}$ is not valid. Limit can be distributed only in case both limits on RHS exists.

Comment: Ok, my fault. I forgot about that. Thanks for information.

Comment: Since you specifically want to avoid solutions that use the fact that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln x = \frac{1}{x}$ (which is tantamount to a common definition of $\ln$, namely, $\ln x := \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$), what definition of $\ln$ are you using here?

Comment: @Travis in fairness to the OP, they do mention that they understand $ln(x)$ as log $x$ to the base $e$, at the bottom of the question.

Comment: We understand $ln(x)$ as Inverse function of $e^x$

Comment: @Kiwi please have a look at this link. It gives a very good proof of this derivative from first principles: http://www.themathpage.com/acalc/exponential.htm#derivative

Comment: @Kiwi Are you permitted to use the derivative of $e^x$ then?

Comment: No, unfortunetly I am not permitted to use any kind of derivative.

Comment: @Travis I think the link in my comment above is pretty much what the OP is looking for. It is all based on a definition of $e^x$ as the limit $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$, as $n$ goes off to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

$\lim \limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{\ln\frac{x}{a}}{x-a} = \lim \limits_{x \to a} \dfrac{\ln\frac{x}{a}}{a(\frac{x}{a} - 1)} = \frac {1} {a}  \lim \limits_{x \to a} \dfrac{\ln\frac{x}{a}}{(\frac{x}{a} - 1) }$.

Now use the composition law for limits to see that

$\lim \limits_{y \to 1} \dfrac{\ln{y}} {y - 1} = 1 $
 and
$\frac{1} {a} \lim \limits_{y \to 1} \dfrac{\ln{y}} {y - 1} =\frac{1} {a} $

(if you're not allowed to use the last formula... prove it!)

We note that, for the logarithmic proprieties,

$\lim \limits_{y \to 1} \dfrac{\ln{y}} {y - 1} = \lim \limits_{y \to 1} \ln {y^\frac{1}{(y - 1)}}$

Now, let
$ y - 1 := \frac{1} {t} $. 
It's obvious that ${ t\to \infty} $ when $ {y\to 1}$.
You're left with
$\lim \limits_{t\to \infty}\ln{(1 + \frac{1} {t})^t}$
and, using the identity 
$\lim \limits_{t\to \infty} ({1 + \frac {1} {t})^t = e} $

the thesis follows from the composition law for limits.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use L'Hôpital's rule. You can think another way, try Taylor expantion for $ln(x)$ at $x=a$.
$ln(x)=ln(a)+\frac{1}{a}(x-a)+(-\frac{1}{a^2})\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}+O(x-a)$
then,
$\lim \limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{\ln\frac{x}{a}}{x-a}\\
=\lim \limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{\ln(x)-ln(a)}{x-a}\\
=\lim \limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{\frac{1}{a}(x-a)+(-\frac{1}{a^2})\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}+O(x-a)}{x-a}\\
=\frac{1}{a}+\lim \limits_{x \to a}(-\frac{1}{a}\frac{(x-a)}{2}+O(x-a))\\
=\frac{1}{a}$
Still the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)= \dfrac{\ln\frac{x}{a}}{x-a}=\frac{1}{a}\cdot\frac{\ln\frac{x}{a}}{\frac{x}{a}-1}$$  $$\lim \limits_{t \to 1}\dfrac{\ln t}{t-1}=???$$

The tangent to $g(t)=\ln t$ at the point $t=1$ is $$\frac{y-0}{x-1}=g'(1)=\frac{1}{1}=1\iff y=x-1$$ and $g(t)$ being derivable at $t=1$ it coincides in differentials with its tangent. Hence $\lim \limits_{t \to 1}\dfrac{\ln t}{t-1}=1$. Consequently $$\lim \limits_{x \to a}\dfrac{\ln\frac{x}{a}}{x-a}=\frac{1}{a}$$

Comment: The asker  CLEARLY spelled out that he knows what the derivative of $\ln x$ is. How does this sidestep the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. My English is weak, Sir (without Google translator I could not answer in StackExchange)